# Loading huge data to browser by Javascript, then make XML request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, request, large-data

I need to send XML request which contains values and content of files obtained by filling HTML form. There are 5 files, some of them have aprox. 70 MB or more. So I'm using some function in javascript, that loads the contents of the files and another one which assemble XML request and send it.
The problem is: after I hit the button for loading the files, the browser crashes (but I can open this files by browser - and it's ok). Files are too large, so browser can't handle with it.
Any ideas where the problem is? And how to deal with it? I thought It might be in timeout, but really don't know...

Function for loading the files:

```
function getFile1Content() {
  var file = document.getElementById("file_zdr").files[0];
  if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        fileContent1 = evt.target.result;
        loaded++;
        console.log("FC1 " + fileContent1)
    }
    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.log("ERROR FC1");
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: What browser do you use? What kind of information did you get using the F12 tools?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I'm using Opera 52.0. The DevTools are disconnected after crash so I can't tell you so much. But after loading the page there is one message - [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 92ms.

Comment: Even if you can make this work, it's never going to be a pleasant experience for the user. Downloading 70Mb of data to the browser so that you can search it locally is just the wrong approach. You need to send the query to the data, not send the data to the query. That is, you need some logic on the server to do the searching, or at least, partial filtering.

Comment: I know that this is not the clever way how to solve it. But all of this is do for my diploma thesis, which looks like more complicated :-) I'm working with PyWPS framework which expects XML request with different data / user files for executing each process. I'm still beginner with developing web apps, maybe I only don't know, how to solve it better. But thanks for reply, Michael!

Answer (score 0):

How things work is browsers send requests for servers to do all the heavy work. So basically you send a request for the server to do this and return that so the user can use the data.

What it seems like is going on to me here is that you're just trying to load to many files. Why is the browser opening the files? Are you sending them to the server? Or are you searching through them? Either way, working with multiple large files using your browser isn't ever a good idea.

If you're trying to search through the files: You should send your files to a server, using a file upload form, `<form><input accept="*" type="upload"></form>` and have the server save them temporarily, search through them after they have been sent, and return what you were trying to show the user.

I willing to help you work this out!